# LinearLayout divider lines not rendering

Tags: android, android-layout

I have an issue. The vertical divider lines on a LinearLayout is not rendering for me. Oddly enough it renders in the 'Preview' but not when the app is running. In fact, the divider lines only appear when I add a child to one of the LinearLayout's children.

The divider also works in other .xml files but not in this one.

Any help would be appreciated.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fillViewport="true"
            android:orientation="vertical">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/calendar_inner_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/calendar_hour_col"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/column_0"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:background="@drawable/rounded_borders"
            android:backgroundTint="@android:color/holo_blue_light"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"/>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/calendar_events_container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/calendar_hour_container"
            android:baselineAligned="false"
            android:divider="@drawable/vertical_divider"
            android:showDividers="middle">

            <!-- The dividers here only show if the FrameLayout has children. 
            However if the FrameLayout is empty, no divider appears. -->
            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@+id/suday_col"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@color/mediumGray"/>
          <!-- More days etc..-->
        </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

It is as if though the FrameLayout's within the LinearLayout's are empty. But since I set `fillViewPort = true` on the ScrollView it should fill the entire screen no?

Answer (score 0):

Alright so I couldn't really figure out why the height of the FrameLayout was zero so I had a workaround that may work for someone with a similar layout.

Since the calendar_hour_col FrameLayout will always be the correct size I simply added this to the LinearLayout to match it's size

```
android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/calendar_hour_col"
android:layout_alignTop="@+id/calendar_hour_col"
android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/calendar_hour_col"
```